# Line length limit for cat reading from keyboard

Tags: ubuntu, cat, clipboard

I have a single line of about 30000 characters (and no newline) in my clipboard. I want to put that into a file. I tried the following command in a GNOME terminal (Ubuntu 20.04):

```
cat > file.ext
```

and then pasted the line using `shift+ctrl+V`.

The file ended up with only 4096 characters.

I can successfully create the file by typing

```
gedit file.ext
```

and then pasting the line with `ctrl+V` and closing the text editor. But why can't I do it with a command-line utility like `cat`?

Comment: `cat` isn't the issue. I don't know what is, but it isn't `cat`

Comment: The Linux terminal driver / line editor is: "The maximum line length is 4096 chars (including the terminating newline character); lines longer than 4096 chars are truncated." See the linked post

Comment: If you want to copy to and from the clipboard or X selection in the terminal, see `man xsel`.  xsel can work with the primary selection, secondary selection, or the clipboard (and note that the interactions between these three and your terminal and various apps takes some getting used to).  xsel can read from stdin or write to stdout.   BTW, I occasionally (at least once a week or so) use xsel to copy/paste very large text selections (tens of thousands of lines - because it's much easier to pipe something into `xsel -i` than it is to manually select & copy it from the terminal buffer)

Answer (score -2):

The max line length is 4096 chars, so you can't paste 30k as you mention.
What you could do is try to separate it by creating a python script that reads the line and separates it.

> The maximum line length is 4096 chars (including the terminating newline character); lines longer than 4096 chars are truncated. After 4095 characters, input processing (e.g., ISIG and ECHO* processing) continues, but any input data after 4095 characters up to (but not including) any terminating newline is discarded. This ensures that the terminal can always receive more input until at least one line can be read.

Comment: just a repetition of the answer that was linked as duplicate, not new information. In this case, it's desirable to just leave it at the duplicate. We're not trying to maximize text on this website, we're optimizing usefulness!